# Android Wear Layout starts too low

Tags: android, layout, android-wear-2.0

I have a problem with a fragment layout for Wear project. I have a WearActivity which just hosts a FragmentContainerView to support navigation graph. Inside I have a HomeFragment with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxedEdges="all">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llWearContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/notifications_ibtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/station_name_tv"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:text="12th St. Oakland City Center Station"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/find_station_tv"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/button_find_station"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceButton"
                android:textColor="@color/find_change_station_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/find_station_tv1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/button_find_station"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceButton"
                android:textColor="@color/find_change_station_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/find_station_tv2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/button_find_station"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceButton"
                android:textColor="@color/find_change_station_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/find_station_tv3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/button_find_station"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceButton"
                android:textColor="@color/find_change_station_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity layout is just this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_wear" />
```

[image: This is the end result. The layout doesn't start from the top]

I've tried several other root viewgroups but the end result is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a toolbar controller class that set a transparent status bar for the Activity. Really specific to the project.